# Parse several json.stringify records from one file?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

At intervals I am collecting data records that should be stored in append-mode to the end of a certain file; I am using json.stringify to render them as text. Later, when I connect to my server, I want to send all those records to the server. Doesn't look like json.parse is capable of handling more than one record; consecutive records are going to make it unhappy. Is there a well-known solution to this problem?

Here's a test program:

```
fs = require("fs");

const record1 = {
name: "Sarah",
age: 25
};
const record2 = {
name: "Joseph",
age: 34
};

function write() {
  var t1 = JSON.stringify(record1);
  var t2 = JSON.stringify(record2);
  fs.appendFileSync("test.json", t1);
  fs.appendFileSync("test.json", t2);
}

function read() {
  text = fs.readFileSync("test.json");
  var v1 = JSON.parse(text);
  console.log(v1);
}

write();
read();
```

Here's the file test.json:

```
{"name":"Sarah","age":25}{"name":"Joseph","age":34}
```

and here's the result:

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 25
```

So what's the best way to come back and read those two separate records?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without having a working example here. Please include your attempts. My initial response is to simply loop over each subsequent record and parse each individually.

Comment: Since you are appending to the file individually, it's not creating a file of valid JSON, but only individual lines. When reading and parsing the entire file, JS would expect an array of objects. I think the best solution would be to rewrite the file each time such that it's valid JSON. Next best would be to make it valid when you read it. Try adding `[` and `]` to the beginning and end of your "JSON" and replacing `}{` with `},{`